# Xiaomi does not connect ws, other mobile phones yes

Tags: java, android, web-services, connection, xiaomi

i have a problem in the APP im developing with my Xiaomi Mi 9 SE that don´t have with my other (older) phones like BQ M5 or some Samsung.

My APP connects to a Web Service to get some information. I have 3 enviroments for this Web Service: Test (in a PC in local LAN), preproduction and production.

Test:  "http://10.60.8.223:8080/ws/webservice.wsdl"; (Xiaomi dont connect, others yes)

PRE:   "https://ws-pre.myaplication.com/ws/webservice.wsdl"; (All connect correct)

PRO:   "https://ws-pro.myaplication.com/ws/webservice.wsdl"; (All connect correct)

With any other mobile phones I connect to the 3 enviroments, but with the Xiaomi i cannot connect to the TEST url where I am debugging the web service.

Do you know what is happening?
What can I try?
Maybe Xiaomi blocks http conection but admits https?

Thank you so much in advance.
Adrián.

Comment: What is the error in logs when calling api?

Comment: D/Login: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 10.60.8.223 not permitted

Comment: Regarding error message I can see that Xiaomi is restricting security and allows only https, you could try using free service like https://ngrok.com/ to tunnel your localhost HTTP to web-accessible https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it:

Create an xml file called network_security_config.xml in RES folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

in Android Manifest, inside application tag:

```
<application
    ...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```